# How to count text values

Tags: qgis, vector, text, count

My issue is to count text values from vector layer. I got a layer with streets for one of administrative region and it's names in column. It looks like this

- Id   Street_name

  1. XYZ
  2. XYZ
  3. ABC
  4. XYZ . . .
  5. ABC

And so on.

My goal is to count the frequency of each street name in this layer. So the result can look like :

- Street_name  Count
- ABC            3
- XYZ            2
- ZZY            1

I know that in ArcMap 'summarize' will be helpful. But how to do it in QgiS? Statist plugin doesn't offer such possibility.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely, you need a "Group stats" plugin:
a litle tutorial from Anita Graser:
https://anitagraser.com/2013/02/02/group-stats-tutorial/

It works like a dynamic table in Excel.

Comment: Thank You for this suggestion! This plugin seems to be very helpful but unfortunately it's not working with my Qgis 2.12.  Is there any other option?

Comment: "Group stats" plugin works very well in this version, What problem do you have? You must to use Column=[Street_name], Value=[Street_name], and columns=Count and then press "Calculate".

Answer (score 3):

Just create a virtual layer using the Add/edit virtual layer button.

[image]

Very simple and very powerfull:

```
select count(*), Street_name from mytable group by Street_name
```

[image]